# Decision tree with SURF algorithm in Accord.net

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, face-recognition, surf, accord.net

I want to make a decision tree for face recognition.
I have made this simple program to learn just 8 images and I don't know if it will finally work. (I used Accord.Net because it is a really good library.....thanks César Souza).

BagOfVisualWords Class is what I have used because I am working on SURF feature extraction that is different in count from one image to another.
However, a null reference error (for ff variable) appears when running the program

This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DecisionTree tree;
    string pathofdataset;
    Bitmap[] DatasetImages = new Bitmap[8];
    double[][] features;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                pathofdataset= fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString()+pathofdataset, "Message");
            }
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathofdataset);
            FileInfo[] images = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            int k = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo image in images)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(image.Name);
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = k;
                DatasetImages[k] =new Bitmap(pathofdataset + "\\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Accord.Math.Random.Generator.Seed = 0;
        BagOfVisualWords bow = new BagOfVisualWords(10);            
        bow.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;           
        bow.Learn(DatasetImages);            
        features = bow.Transform(DatasetImages);  
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[][] inputs = features.ToInt32();
        int [] outputs = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7};
        int[] weight = new int[8];            
        ID3Learning teacher = new ID3Learning();
        tree = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
        double error = new ZeroOneLoss(outputs).Loss(tree.Decide(inputs));
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg,*.png)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
        }

        dlg.Dispose();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        Bitmap testimage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
        SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector SURF = new SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector();
        var testimagesurf=  SURF.ProcessImage(testimage);
        testimagesurf.ToArray();
        MessageBox.Show("Test "+testimagesurf.Count());
        BagOfVisualWords bowtest = new BagOfVisualWords(10);
        bowtest.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
        var ff= bowtest.Transform(testimagesurf);
        ff.ToInt32();
        var predicted = tree.Decide(ff);
        MessageBox.Show("Test" + predicted);
    }
}
```

This is image of the program interface:

[image]

Comment: Please any one help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I updated it to the following code for button 4 the result is (1 or -1 or 3) that is wrong result

Comment: private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap[] testimage = new Bitmap[1];
            testimage[0]=(Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            BagOfVisualWords bowtest = new BagOfVisualWords(10);
            bowtest.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
            bowtest.Learn(testimage);
            var ff = bowtest.Transform(testimage);
            ff.ToInt32();
            var predicted = tree.Decide(ff);
            var gg=predicted.Length;
            MessageBox.Show("Test" + predicted[0]);

        }